# Azure functions call web api as authorized

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have a web api with the [Authorize] attribute on each controller. Azure AD is used for sign in.
Everything works fine from my mobile app where I just generate a bearer token and call the web api with the authed request.

What I would like to get working now is to call the same web api from an Azure function but I don't find any examples on how to do this. I find examples on how to protect my function using Azure AD but not how to call a protected API.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this on-behalf-of tutorial may help:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/

Basically, set up AAD for the azure function. Then, in your function, get a token on behalf of the authenticated user and use it to call your web api, seen in this code:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L127

Comment: Service Principal may also be worth looking into if the web API doesn't need the user context: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-dotnet-service-principal-auth

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!